# How to bind a df to a list of df

Tags: r

I have a list of df `lst1` and a df for variable name and label `Label`. How can I bind `Label` with each df in `lst`. I understand that all cols in `lst` will be charters and won't be able to used again for analysis. But that is what I want. How should I do that?

```
lst<-list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("1953-07-07", 
"1963-07-02", "1940-09-11", "1955-12-31", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("2016-03-14", 
"2017-04-04", NA, "2016-05-02", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c(NA, 
NA, "UN-UNK-2015", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), Visit = c("Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"
), VISND = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

Label<-structure(list(Var = c("SubjectID", "BRTHDTC", "SEX", "DSDT", 
"DSDT_P", "Visit", "VISND"), label = c("Subject ID", "Birthday", 
"Gender", "DS Date", "DS Date Prob", "Date of Visit", "ND Visit"
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

The expected df in lst will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
out <- map(lst, ~ bind_rows(as.list(deframe(Label)[names(.x)]), .x))
```

-output

```
out
$Demographics
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 Subject ID Birthday   Gender
2 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female
3 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female
4 101-03-103 1940-09-11 Male  
5 101-04-104 1955-12-31 Male  
6 104-05-201 1950-12-04 Female

$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P      
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       
1 Subject ID DS Date    DS Date Prob
2 101-01-101 2016-03-14 <NA>        
3 101-02-102 2017-04-04 <NA>        
4 101-03-103 <NA>       UN-UNK-2015 
5 101-04-104 2016-05-02 <NA>        
6 104-05-201 2018-07-06 <NA>        

$Visits
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND   
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>   
1 Subject ID Date of Visit                ND Visit
2 101-01-101 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>    
3 101-02-102 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>    
4 101-03-103 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>    
5 101-04-104 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>    
6 104-05-201 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>
```

---

If we want the other way

```
map(lst, ~ {
    nm1 <- deframe(Label)[names(.x)]
    bind_rows(as.list(setNames(names(nm1), nm1)), setNames(.x, nm1)) })
```

-output

```
$Demographics
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Subject ID` Birthday   Gender
  <chr>        <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID    BRTHDTC    SEX   
2 101-01-101   1953-07-07 Female
3 101-02-102   1963-07-02 Female
4 101-03-103   1940-09-11 Male  
5 101-04-104   1955-12-31 Male  
6 104-05-201   1950-12-04 Female

$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Subject ID` `DS Date`  `DS Date Prob`
  <chr>        <chr>      <chr>         
1 SubjectID    DSDT       DSDT_P        
2 101-01-101   2016-03-14 <NA>          
3 101-02-102   2017-04-04 <NA>          
4 101-03-103   <NA>       UN-UNK-2015   
5 101-04-104   2016-05-02 <NA>          
6 104-05-201   2018-07-06 <NA>          

$Visits
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Subject ID` `Date of Visit`              `ND Visit`
  <chr>        <chr>                        <chr>     
1 SubjectID    Visit                        VISND     
2 101-01-101   Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>      
3 101-02-102   Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>      
4 101-03-103   Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>      
5 101-04-104   Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>      
6 104-05-201   Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>
```

Comment: If I want label to the first row, by any chance that is doable?

Comment: @Stataq isn't that now the first row `1 Subject ID Date of Visit                ND Visit`

Comment: Sorry, I mean as 1 row of the whole thing, so it will looks like label, variable, variable inputs.

Comment: @Stataq Sorry, i am not getting what you meant.  What do you meant by 1row of the whole thing?  Is it just a single string

Comment: @Stataq can you please update your post with a picture of what you meant

Comment: Yes, the ideal output is at the bottom of my post. :D

Comment: @Stataq So, you meant to name the columns with the ones that are in the current first row and get the column name in first row?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want.

Comment: Wonderful. That is exactly what I looking for. :D Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For these sort of problems where you need to map names to names, I like to use named vectors (with the function `setNames()`) the way you would use dictionaries in python. Then you can use it to extract the vector of labels that you want to prepend to each data.frame.

```
var2label = setNames(Label$label, nm = Label$Var)

new_df_list = lapply(lst, function(L){

 col_names = names(L)
 col_labels = var2label[col_names]
 
 df = rbind(col_labels, data.frame(L))

 return(df)

})
```

Output of the first data.frame

```
> new_df_list[[1]]
   SubjectID    BRTHDTC    SEX
1 Subject ID   Birthday Gender
2 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female
3 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female
4 101-03-103 1940-09-11   Male
5 101-04-104 1955-12-31   Male
6 104-05-201 1950-12-04 Female
```